# List Permission - user and owner

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-permissions

I am user of a group site, I have created a list in that group. I want to give access to specified people in the group. How can I give? Is there restrictions that only site owner can able to give permission for the list even if user created it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you use SharePoint Online modern team site?

If that’s the case, you can grant user permission to this site via gear button in the top right corner of the page->Site Permissions->click Invite people or Advanced permissions settings.

If you want to grant user permission to a list, click gear button in the top right corner of the page->List settings->permissions for this list->click Stop Inheriting Permissions, then click Grant Permissions to invite specific users.

If you use SharePoint on-premise, you can click site settings->site permissions to grant permission with people.

If the user wants to grant permission to the site, the user needs to have "Manage Permissions" permission, you need to use Site owner account or create a custom permission level and tick the "Manage Permissions" permission, then grant to the relevant user.

Comment: Yes. I have been using SharePoint modern team site. The above listed cases match only for the Site owner. If the member of the group creates a list ,he can't able to see the Permissions for the list option. Only the site owner has the access to grant permissions even it has created by site member. Is there any possible way that the member of the group grant/restrict permission for the list?

Comment: It's by design that users of team site members group only have "Edit" permission level, which not include "manage permission". As a workaround, site owner can copy the Edit permission level and tick "manage permission" under site permissions, save as a custom permission level, finally, grant this custom permission level to site members group in site permissions settings.